# How to open and read an FIFO

Tags: java, android

Guys please suggest me some good way to handle below in java.

I need to open an FIFO , check if there is any error in opening , then

Read from the Fifo and write into an File .

I will really glad if anyone could help me with this .

Comment: FIFO as in a queue (LinkedList implements Queue in java)?

Comment: Yes . Some one will keep writing into it and i need to open and read it .

Comment: So they have written the FIFO to a text file for example, and we need to read it? What kind of objects are stored in the queue? Are the objects serialization? Are the objects seperated by spaces, newlines, or commas?

Comment: It wont be a text file . They will be writing a audio video data into that fifo . I need to read that data and create a file with some extensions like .ts or .mp4

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what is the format of the audio/video data in the file? Can you give an example in the question?

Comment: It is basically an android application . A transport stream (.ts) will be playing on the screen , someone will read that stream and write into a a file which is a FIfo , format will be 640*480 , and audio type will be AAC and video H264 , this all happen in C world. The main question is what is best way to open an that Fifo in Java world , i mean something like Input stream and output stream , or may buffered input stream or a pipe may be. I am just confused how do i use any of them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42548/discussion-between-sajidkhan-and-bucco)

Answer (score 4):

To read a fifo with java, you treat it like a regular file, I used the code below to verify

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

class catfile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException, java.io.IOException {
    byte[] b = getBytesFromInputStream(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
    System.out.print(new String(b));
    }
    public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws java.io.IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream res = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0x10000]; /* 0x10000 = 65536 */
    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = is.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) >= 0) {
        res.write(bytes, 0, numRead);
    }
    return res.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

the test went as follows

```
$ rm -f aaa; mkfifo aaa; (sleep 5; date >> aaa) &
$ javac catfile.java && java -ea -cp . catfile aaa
Thu Dec  5 08:18:51 UTC 2013
```